# Why does OpenCV Stitcher Class fail for image sub sections?

Tags: python, opencv, image-stitching, opencv-stitching

I am trying to stitch panoramas using the [OpenCV Stitcher Class](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/samples/python/stitching_detailed.py) in Python. The input data consists of partly overlapping images, but sometimes also images showing a sub section of another image, e.g.:

[image: 1st input] [image: 2nd input]

Whenever there are images showing a sub section, the stitching either fails ("Need more images" or "Camera parameters adjusting failed.") or leaves out the image showing the subsection. This also applies to images that are overlapping almost completely (>~90%).

There are sufficient features and matches found. The homography gets estimated correctly; see this output from the `cv.draw_matches()` function:

[image]

I have tried different feature detection methods (ORB, AKAZE, SIFT, SURF) as well as tuning various other parameters like bundle adjustment, warp type and confidence (`conf_thresh`).

It is essential for my application, that all images are included in the panorama, even when they show an area already covered by previous images.

What am I doing wrong? Are there any other methods for generating image stitchings using opencv-python?

Comment: does "subsection" mean that you sliced a region from a larger image? then give it *copies* of your array slices. -- if you can prepare a [mre] (or if existing sample code shows the issue already), that would be a vital part of a bug report.

Comment: The linked sample code of the [stitching_detailed.py](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/samples/python/stitching_detailed.py) shows the issue already. Originally, I do not slice regions from a larger image, I'm using images from multiple cameras with different fields of view. So "subsection" means an image of the same scenery but taken with a smaller field of view than some of the other images.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I can't post my original input data due to copyright issues. But the issue occurs in any data sets containing subsections, such as the images in my original post (taken from the [OpenCV example data](https://github.com/opencv/opencv_extra/tree/4.x/testdata/stitching)), where I indeed sliced a region from the larger image.

Comment: ok then, make sure you're using a current release of opencv (nothing stale) and check if this hasn't already been reported as an issue.

Answer (score 1):

> Are there any other methods for generating image stitchings using
> opencv-python?

The [stitching package](https://github.com/lukasalexanderweber/stitching) uses opencv-python and offers a lot of insight possibilities into the stitching process using the [tutorial](https://github.com/lukasalexanderweber/stitching_tutorial/blob/master/docs/Stitching%20Tutorial.md)